# Angular 4 - how to detect class instance value update?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a **Maths** class in which I can change the **type of operation**.

```
export class Maths {
   private static _instance: Maths = new Maths();
   type: string = "ADD";

   constructor() {
     Maths._instance = this;
   }

   public static getInstance(): Maths {
     console.log("Instance Provided");
     return Maths._instance;
   }

   // change operation here
   changeType(newType) {
     type = newType;
   }
}
```

In one of my component I have Maths class's instance, here I need to detect changes in this instance.. but its not working. code is as follows,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Maths } from './Maths';

@Component({
  selector: 'operation-cmp',
  template: ''
})

export class OperationComponent {
  mathsType: Maths;
  constructor() {

     //Maths instance
     this.mathsType = Maths.getInstance();

     // Trying to detect instance change
     if(this.mathsType.type == "MULTIPLY") {
        //Do something here
     }
}
```

My app component sets this Maths class's **type** on button click as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Maths } from './Maths';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

 maths;
 type = "MULTIPLY"

 constructor() {

 }

 // on button click calling this function
 changeType() {
  this.maths = Maths.getInstance()
  this.maths.changeType(type);
 }
}
```

My doubt is, how do I detect Maths class's instance value change in OperationComponent. In OperationComponent need to do some functionality based on the type.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Make use of a [shared Service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or if they have a parent child relation ship go for [event emitters](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**Subject**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) type. Have an instance of Subject in the Maths class and notify from it, when `changeType` was called.

```
export class Maths {
   private static _instance: Maths = new Maths();
   private typeChange: Subject = new Subject();
   type: string = "ADD";

   constructor() {
     Maths._instance = this;
   }

   public static getInstance(): Maths {
     console.log("Instance Provided");
     return Maths._instance;
   }

   public changeType(newType) {
     this.type = newType;
     this.typeChange.next(); // Put notification into container
   }

   public onTypeChange() : Subject {
      return this.typeChange;
   }
}
```

And in the `OperationComponent` get the subject and subscribe on it.

```
export class OperationComponent implements OnInit {

  mathsType: Maths;

  constructor() {
     this.mathsType = Maths.getInstance();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.mathsType.onTypeChange().subscribe(data => /*Your logic here*/)
  }

}
```

Comment: this better suits a comment

Comment: I am filling the answer

Comment: great :D this was awsome my first exp, like a reservation

Comment: @RahulSingh :D. I have finished